# JSPDF : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I have table with image i want export table data with image to pdf with JSPDF but i got message

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

This is my code any body can help me?

```js
function downloadPDF() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('basic-datatable');
  var imgElements = document.querySelectorAll('#basic-datatable tbody img');
  // var data = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(elem);
  var images = [];
  var i = 0;

  var canvas = document.querySelector('#myChart');
  var canvasImg = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0); //creates image
  var doc = new jsPDF('landscape'); //creates PDF from img
  doc.text("Laporan Peminjaman Inventaris", 110, 25);
  doc.addImage(canvasImg, 'png', 10, 45, 280, 150);
  doc.addPage();
  var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(document.getElementById("basic-datatable"));
  doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data, {
    // bodyStyles: {rowHeight: 30},
    drawCell: function(cell, opts) {
      if (opts.column.dataKey === 7) {
        var img = imgElements[opts.row.index];
        images.push({
          url: img,
          x: cell.textPos.x,
          y: cell.textPos.y
        });
        i++;
      }
    },
    addPageContent: function() {
      for (var z = 0; z < images.length; z++) {
        doc.addImage(images[z].url, images[z].x, images[z].y, 20, 20);
      }
    }
  });
  var options = {
    beforePageContent: header,
    // startY: doc.autoTableEndPosY() + 20
  };

  doc.save('LaporanDataPeminjaman.pdf');
  window.history.back();
}
```

Comment: Which line of code is the error referencing? Is it your code (eg `for (var z = 0; z < images.length; z++) {`) or some library code?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when autotable can't get a table.

The error is for sure between this lines:
var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(document.getElementById("basic-datatable"));
doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data, {...})

Maybe you are not correctly referencing the table.

It may also be that the line doc.autoTableHtmlToJson (document.getElementById ("basic-datatable")), is unnecessary and that you only need to pass the id of the element to doc.autoTable (IdOfDomElement, res.data, {...} )

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to StackOverflow! It's great to see that you've identified the source of the error, but could you possibly provide some context for the poster? Why might he not be getting the AutoTable he expects?

Comment: Yes, in my case just referring to the table id solved the problem.